# Finding an eigenvectors and eigenvalues to a matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I got a question :

Given A a matrix which the sum of all elements in each row equals to a constant $\alpha$, find eigenvector and eigenvalue it is belong to.

I have no clue from where to start, maybe something about that the elements in each row are all linear combination of the same vector.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Think of how multiplication of a matrix with a column vector works.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, you multiply the vector in each row with some column vector, and they all equal to the same value, $\alpha$.
I don't get how to keep up from here.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the vector $v$ with each entry equal to $1$.

Comment: the eigenvalue is alpha and the eigenvector is 1 (dimension equals to n)

Comment: @NeilRauch if by "...and the eigenvector is 1" you mean the vector with every entry equal to $1$, then yes.